# Witcher 3: activating alternate signs

Tags: the-witcher-3

I finished the game without developing my character (I know that sounds stupid!) Now I want to activate the alternate igni sign (to kill the toad prince), but I cannot do it although I have 33 points available (the box on the bottom left in the character screen says Points Available 33).

Despite having 33 points in total, the points available in the branch for Signs is 0! So, I don't see how to use those 33 points..?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'Points in Branch: 0' at the top of the Signs section is just telling you that you have not currently spent any Skill Points on signs. This is useful information because the rows in the table are unlocked as you spend more points in the table.

So to begin just select an entry in the first row and use 'Acquire Ability'. Then you can continue to upgrade or acquire abilities.

Comment: thanks a lot! this is all I needed to know

Answer (score 0):

You have to start at the top, and fully complete each box before moving down to the next one. To get all the way to the Pyromaniac in igni you need to have spent 28 points. You do this by increasing more signs than just igni. Progress as far as you can down the igni column and you will then see how many more points need to be spent before you can go any further down.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/318812)